# Cocoa pods headers to be accessed using <> or ""

Tags: ios, import, xcode6, cocoapods

My Pod file content is listed below

```
pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1"

pod 'Google-API-Client'
```

I am able to import the YTPPlayer using angle brackets. This is user specific file, which should be imported with "".

```
#import <YTPlayerView.h>
```

When I try to type import "Y" nothing populates. Snapshot of HeaderSearch Path is shown below.

I did try to turn "Always Search User Header Paths" to yes, still import works only with angle brackets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just have to import #import "YTPlayerView.h" if it does not populates write in manually as it is also given in the documentation for youtube-ios-player-helper.Build your project and it should build it successfully.

The Documentation describes step by step information to install cocoapods and how to use it.

Link for the documentation :https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper#installation